# How does one prove that specific gravity is the fraction of the object sunk in water?

Tags: fluid-statics

This is mentioned at 1:01 in this video of khan academy https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/fluids/density-and-pressure/v/specific-gravity

But I can not find an answer to how this became to be true anywhere... Is there a way to mathematically prove this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for an object to float, regardless of how much is submerged, the net vertical force on the object has to be zero. That means the downward weight of the object must equal the upward buoyant force on the object. Or

$$V_{o}ρ_{o}g=V_{l}ρ_{l}g$$

The left side of the equation is the total weight of the object. $V_o$ is the total volume of the object, not necessarily the submerged volume of the object, $ρ_{o}$ is the specific gravity of the object (the ratio of its density to the density of water), and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity near the earth's surface.

The right side of the equation is the buoyant force, which is the weight of the volume of water displaced.  $V_l$ is the volume of the water displaced by the submerged volume of the object and $ρ_{l}=1$ is the specific gravity of water.

The fraction of the object submerged is the ratio of the volume of the liquid displaced, $V_l$ to the total volume of the object, $V_o$ or

$$\frac{V_l}{V_o}=\frac{ρ_o}{ρ_l}=ρ_o$$

Which says the fraction of the object submerged in water equals its specific gravity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Astounding I kept putting the Vs as same on both side and they kept cancelling.. Very helpful for me THank yoU!!